# Multilevel static route architecture react router v4

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, config

I am trying to work on multilevel architecture in a way that would allow me to possibly have more than one route leading to the same component and still be able to reach other components.

My understanding of react-router-config (the static version of react router v4) is a bit limited and as the documentation does not seem to be thorough I'd like for you to help me.

Here is the route config:

```
const routes = [
    {
        component : Root,
        routes    : [
            {
                path      : '/*',
                component : Layout,
                routes    : [
                    {
                        path      : '/',
                        exact     : true,
                        component : ComponentOne,
                    },
                    {
                        path      : '/route-2,
                        exact     : true,
                        component : ComponentTwo,
                    },
                    {
                        path      : '/complex-route',
                        component : ComplexComponent,
                        routes    : [
                            {
                                path      : '/complex-route/:all',
                                component : ComplexComponentTabAll,
                            },
                            {
                                path      : '/complex-route/tab-1',
                                exact     : true,
                                component : ComplexComponentTabOne,
                            },
                            {
                                path      : '/complex-route/tab-2',
                                exact     : true,
                                component : ComplexComponentTabTwo,
                            },
                        ],
                    },
                    {
                        path      : '*',
                        exact     : true,
                        component : NotFound,
                    },
                ],

            },
            {
                path      : '*',
                component : NotFound,
            },
        ],
    },
];

// ============================================================
// Exports
export default routes;
```

here is the component Layout:

```
const Layout = ({ route }) => (
    <div>
        <Menu />
        <MainBlock>
            <Header>
                {/*some sstuff goes here */}
            </Header>
            <Theatre>
                {renderRoutes(route.routes)}
            </Theatre>
        </MainBlock>
    </div>
);
```

and here is a sample of the complex components

```
const ComplexeComponent = ({ route }) => (
    <div>
        { renderRoutes(route.routes) }
    </div>
);

const ComplexComponentTabAll = () => (
    <div>
        <p> This is the ComplexComponentTabAll </p>
    </div>
);
```

I was expecting some sort of tabing architechture where by using `/complex-route` and/or `/complex-route/:all` ComplexComponent would be the wrapper component in which ComplexeComponentAll would be rendered.

But instead the ComplexComponentAll is either not rendered or rendered twice (depending on my tickering with the routes).

Comment: Not entirely sure what the exact problem is, as `ComplexComponentAll` is not in `routes`, but one issue is having `'/complex-route/:all'` before `'/complex-route/tab-1'` and `'/complex-route/tab-2'`, which will prevent the latter two from showing. Maybe `tab-1` and `tab-2` should be child `routes` of `:all`?

Comment: The `ComplexComponentAll` was a typo, as I change the names of the components.
What I wanted was to be able to access first the "all page"  via either `/complex-route` or `/complex-route/:all` and then being able to access tab-1 & tab-2, in short Id like to access `ComplexComponentTabAll` by `/`or `/all`.
Is that a bit more clear ?

Comment: Possibly `'/complex-route/(all)?'` with `exact: true` is what you want, as it matches only  `/complex-route` and `/complex-route/all`. Don't use `:all` as this will always match.

Comment: You are a star, I think this is working, it was the regex-path that was wrong and also the position of the route like you said in your second post.
If you reply to this question i'll be more than happy to validate your answer !!
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Sure, glad to help! I've put a short summary in the answer section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that the named-parameter route `/complex-route/:all` (which matches anything below `/complex-route/`) appeared before the `/complex-route/tab-1` and `/complex-route/tab-2` routes. As `react-router-config` uses `<Switch>` internally, which only shows the first match, the other two routes would never show.

Making `/complex-route/:all` the last route kind of fixes it, but using an exact route with a regular expression to only match `/complex-route` and `/complex-route/all` is a cleaner solution:

```
{
    path      : '/complex-route/(all)?',
    exact     : true,
    component : ComplexComponentTabAll,
}
```

For more info on the syntax of the `path` prop of `react-router-config` and `react-router`, check out the [`path-to-regexp` docs](https://github.com/pillarjs/path-to-regexp#usage).